# Error after form submission in JQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile and submitting a form in it. The form is submitted via post method and is sent to a php file. The form is getting submitted without any problem and submitted data is displayed in the php page. But once I refresh the page, I am getting Undefined index notice and the data is gone. The dialog window asking me for form re submission confirmation,like it normally does on refreshing is also not coming.

Answer (score 1):

This is because jQuery mobile is sending the form via AJAX and not doing a normal POST request.

> In jQuery Mobile, form submissions are automatically handled using
>   Ajax whenever possible, creating a smooth transition between the form
>   and the result page.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html